# ParserError: Expected ';' but got identifier

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity

I am trying to create a contract for an ERC20 token and am getting this error when I try to deploy it:

contracts/YourToken.sol:11:33: ParserError: Expected ';' but got identifier
const yourToken = await deployments.get("plonCoin");

Any thoughts on why this might be happening?

[image]

Comment: I am no C# expert, but what is that \*\*  in (10 ** 18)?

Comment: @Pred The two asterisks mean "to the power of" in Solidity language. So `10 ** 18` is `1000000000000000000`. Solidity doesn't use floating point numbers (only integers), and 18 is a common number of decimals of a token. So the `1000 * (10 ** 18)` is a way to express "1000 tokens with 18 decimals".

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing together Solidity code of the contract and JavasScript code of an off-chain app working with the contract.

```
const yourToken = await deployments.get("plonCoin");
const result = await yourToken.transfer("<address>", utils.parseEther("1000"));
```

This is the JS code that doesn't belong to the contract.